# unittests for infinite loop

Tags: python, unit-testing

I am stucked at this code for creating unittest for infinite loop.

```
try:
  while True:
    time.sleep(60)
except:
  fun()
```

Please let me know how can we create unittests for infinite loop?

Comment: You could `unittest.mock` out `time.sleep` to have various [`side_effect`s](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.side_effect).

Comment: but it will stick go into infinite loop as While True is used. how can we resolve the same?

Comment: Please *actually read* the documentation - the side effect can be *"an exception (class or instance) to be raised"*, allowing you to end the loop when you choose.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

What behaviour are you testing? There doesn't appear to be any side effects or return value here. There isn't really anything to test. If it's just that `fun` is called after the loop then that sounds like over-specification. If it's just that some invariant is maintained after the loop ends then you can patch `sleep` to throw an exception, and then examine the state after the function has run.

```
from unittest import TestCase, main
from unittest.mock import patch

import module_under_test

class TestLoop(TestCase):
    # patch sleep to allow loop to exit
    @patch("time.sleep", side_effect=InterruptedError)
    def test_state_reset(self, mocked_sleep):
        # given
        obj = module_under_test.SomeClass()

        # when
        obj.infinite_loop()

        # then assert that state is maintained
        self.assertFalse(obj.running)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**module_under_test.py**

```
import time

class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.running = False

    def fun(self):
        self.running = False

    def infinite_loop(self):
        self.running = True
        try:
            while True:
                time.sleep(60)
        except:
            self.fun()
```

Answer (score 4):

You could code the infinite loop using the [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) funсtion instead of `while True: ...`. This might make the code slightly less efficient, but it makes it possible to [mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) the infinite loop:

```
import itertools

try:
    for _ in itertools.count():
        time.sleep(60)
except:
    fun()
```

Then in your test do:

```
from unittest.mock import patch

with patch("itertools.count") as mock_count:
    # tests go here
```